# problem with title bar in iphone project

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hii every one

i am creating a grouped table view programatically using the following code table is creating properly but title bar is not displaying where i have done mistake can any one help me   thanx in advance

```
       self.title = @"User Details";

 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                              initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel 
                                              target:self action:@selector(cancel_Clicked:)] autorelease];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                               initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave 
                                               target:self action:@selector(save_Clicked:)] autorelease];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];


         UITableView *tableView1;
        tableView1 = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 415)style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        tableView1.dataSource = self;
        tableView1.delegate = self;
        [self.view addSubview:tableView1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean self.**navigationItem**.title = @"User Details"; ?